# NuGet references in VS

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget, fody

[image]

I am using fody and methodboundaryaspect.fody in this class as NuGet references. The references are installed properly but here it says that it can not find "OnMethodBoundaryAspect" which is part of MethodBoundaryAspect. Does anyone faced a similar issue before?

I already tried: Uninstall/install, reopen VS, restore NuGet packages,Update-Package -reinstall, clear NuGet cache, but nothing worked out.

Comment: Which nuget package did  you install?

Comment: Fody, MethodBoundaryAspect.fody

Comment: Also, which is your project type and l created a framework 4.7.2 project and install `MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody` package, it works well  and l did not face any errors as you said.

Comment: Normally, it should work like this. That is why I asked because it is not.

Comment: Hi, I decided to revert to a point where it was working fine. I absolutely have no clue why it happened.

Answer (score 1):

> I am using fody and methodboundaryaspect.fody in this class as NuGet
>   references. The references are installed properly but here it says
>   that it can not find "OnMethodBoundaryAspect" which is part of
>   MethodBoundaryAspect.

**As for me**, if I install this package in a net framework 4.7.2 project, all works well and do not face the errors as you said. So l am afraid that there is something wrong with your project or VS Environment.

Please try these:

**1)** close VS Instance, delete `.vs`(hidden folder), `obj`,`bin` folder under the solution and then restart your project again.

**2)** disable any third party extensions under `Tools`-->`Extensions and Updates` or just use [devenv /safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019)(start VS) to test whetehr it is caused by any third party extensions or other packages.

**3)** Or just create a new empty c# project and then install this package again to test. If it still gets error, please [repair your VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019). Besides, if your VS is not the latest version, please update it to the latest version.

Hope it could help you.